# Can you repeat last command with flags in bash?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, productivity

Is there a way to repeat your last command with additional flags?

Example:

Say I do this:

```
rm myFavouriteDirectory
```

I will get a reply:

```
rm: myFavouriteDirectory/: is a directory
```

Obviously what I meant to do was:

```
rm -rf myFavouriteDirectory
```

Is there some way to repeat the last command with flags like `!! -rf` (this doesn't work)

Comment: I assume editing the previous line is not an option? (e.g. Cursor up and edit or ESC k $ a options) ?

Comment: Usually you're faster by typing `rm -rf $_`.

Comment: @ott: What if the command is a long one? Also $_ stands only for the last parameter? similar to !$? What if there are multiple parameters?

Comment: @jaychris That's what my `Usually` is meant for. `$_` is for the last parameter from the previous command.

Answer (score 7):

See "HISTORY EXPANSION" in `man bash`.

The closest I'm aware of would be:
`!!:0 -rf !*`

`!!:0` is the first word in the previous command, `!*` is everything but the first (i.e. the arguments).

But in practice I would always type:
`rm -rf !*`

In GNU distributions, `!! -rf` (i.e. putting the flags at the end) would still work for most commands, but it usually won't on BSD and OSX. It depends how the command processes arguments.

Comment: In my bash, !! -rf works (simpler than !!:0 !*). I don't know if this is dependent on the bash version (as you have mentioned about GNU distribution). Mine is "GNU bash, version 3.00.15(1)"

Comment: How the tool (rm in this case) processes arguments is more what I was referring to. GNU utils on Linux generally accept option flags at the end after other arguments, whereas BSD (and OSX) do not. But you make a good point, `!!:0 !* -rf` is completely pointless and no better than `!! -rf`, I'll update my answer.